# Can i insert css counter in content url of pseudo before element

Tags: css, sass, pseudo-element

i want to use just like this but not working .

```
counter-increment: card;
h2{
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0;
    &::before{
        content: url(`../../public/icons/skill${counter(card)}.svg`);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, **NO**. You can't pass other functions such as `attr()` or `counter()` into `url()` function to generate a url string dynamically, yet.

But since you're using sass, you may utilize [`@for`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/for) to achieve it. Although you have to choose a number (such as `50`) that you're sure there are no more than that number of `h2`s in the same hierarchy.

```
h2 {
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0;

    @for $i from 1 through 50 {
        &:nth-of-type(#{$i})::before {
            content: url('../../public/icons/skill#{$i}.svg');
        }
    }
}
```

Basically it generates the following css for you:

```css
h2 {
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0;
}
h2:nth-of-type(1)::before {
  content: url("../../public/icons/skill1.svg");
}
h2:nth-of-type(2)::before {
  content: url("../../public/icons/skill2.svg");
}
h2:nth-of-type(3)::before {
  content: url("../../public/icons/skill3.svg");
}
/* repeats 50 times */
```